# Compare Gmapping map with Ground Truth

Tags: navigation, mapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to find a way of quantitatively comparing a map generated by SLAM_gmapping with the original map (.pgm) used for the stage simulation. I would use this to compare the accuracy of different mapping techniques. I have considered using an image comparison tool (I tried GraphicsMagick), but this comes with some problems. First, the scale of the saved map (rosrun map_server map_saver) is different from the one of the original map. Secondly, the positions of both maps are different. Hence, I would need to superimpose both images exactly using Gimp before comparing them, which is far from precise. Would anyone have any suggestions as to how to achieve my goal? I would either need a reliable way of rescaling the slam map or an independent algorithm to compare them... I have never studied image processing, so this is no easy task for me!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65203/compare-gmapping-map-with-ground-truth/) by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 343 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is my solution so far.

http://answers.ros.org/question/66825/comparing-two-occupancy-grids/

---

Originally posted by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) with karma: 343 on 2013-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1